# pyodbc issue: ODBC driver not found on MacOS

Tags: python, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

My environment

- Python: 3.9.7
- pyodbc:  4.0.32
- OS: MacOS 12.0.1, Apple M1 Max
- DB: Azure SQL
- driver: ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

Running

```
import pyodbc

server   = 'myserver.database.windows.net'
database = 'mydb'
username = 'myuser'
password = 'mypassword'
odbc_driver = '{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}'

conn_str = (
    f"Driver={odbc_driver};"
    f"Server=tcp:{server},1433;"
    f"Database={database};"
    f"Uid={username};"
    f"Pwd={password};"
    "Encrypt=yes;"
    "TrustServerCertificate=no;"
    "Connection Timeout=30;")

print(conn_str)

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
```

outputs

```
Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=mydb;Uid=myuser;Pwd=mypassword;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/....", line 21, in <module>
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Using the same connection string in isql:

```
isql -v -k "Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:<server>,1433;Database=<db>;Uid=<user>;Pwd=<pw>;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

returns `Connected` and queries are possible

Drivers are on my machine, I tried first with `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server`, then installed `ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server` with same result.

[image]

How can I fix this? Created a GitHub issue as well [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/1054)

Comment: Didnt you [ask this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71978696/import-of-pyodbc-fails) yesterday? How is this question different from our last one?

Comment: yesterday I was not able to import pyodbc at all. I asked why I could not import. That I resolved yesterday but then run into a new issue. Both issues are linked, see link on the right

Answer (score 1):

> **Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib**
> **'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0)**
> **(SQLDriverConnect)")**

According to the ***Above Error*** drivers are properly ***not installed*** .However, for `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL server` ,Please follow the official document [***Installing the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on MacOS***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#microsoft-odbc-driver-17-for-sql-server).

Another way to Solve an Error, check whether your driver is installed or not then, follow the driver path
**Example** : ***"/user/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib"*** , Replace ***Driver value*** as shown in below code.

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={/user/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib};SERVER=ServerName,1433;DATABASE=DatabaseName;UID=Username;PWD=password')
```

**Reference:**

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-mac.html#installing-and-configuring-the-odbc-driver-for-macos

Comment: `> ls /opt/homebrew/lib/libmsodbcsql.18.dylib`returns
`/opt/homebrew/lib/libmsodbcsql.18.dylib` but the path in cnxn returns the same error

Answer (score 0):

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
brew tap microsoft/mssql-release https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew- 
mssql-release
brew update
brew install msodbcsql@13.1.9.2 mssql-tools@14.0.6.0
```

These commands are for MacOS exactly. You can check here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Try installing Homebrew natively as per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65383601/2103431. Also, use Python 3.11 and the **--no-binary** flag for the `pyodbc` lib installation.

Make sure you uninstall all **msodbcsq** drivers, **mssql-tools** and **unixodbc** before you begin implementing the fix.

Homebrew installations should go under the folder `/opt/homebrew/` to prevent any complicated linking problems.

**How to check if Homebrew is the problem?**

1. You have linked the `odbcinst.ini` and the `odbc.ini` files according to the troubleshooting [Microsoft instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver16). Also, you have tried changing the entries in `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini` to point to a location where you are sure there is an executable version of the driver and this doesn't help.

Command to check that the lib file is executable, the **x** in the output stands for executable.

```
$ ls -la /usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 localadmin  admin  64  7  4 16:38 /usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib -> /usr/local/Cellar/msodbcsql17/17.1.0.1/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
```

2. When you run `odbcinst -j` the file references in the output start with `/Users/<your_username>/` or `/usr/local/`.

**$ odbcinst -j**

```
unixODBC 2.3.12
DRIVERS............: /Users/<your_username>/.Homebrew/<more_dirs>/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /Users/<your_username>/.Homebrew/<more_dirs>/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /Users/<your_username>/.Homebrew/<more_dirs>/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/<your_username/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

**How to know the problem lies outside of Python?**

Use the CLI `isql` client to test the database connection.

```
isql -v -k 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver <driver_version/13/17/18> for SQL Server};SERVER=<server_name>.database.windows.net;PORT=1443;DATABASE=<db_name>;UID=<db_user>;PWD=<db_pass>'
```

Using `isql` should produce the same error as the Python script.

```
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/Users/Konstantin.Grigorov/Desktop/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib' : file not found
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLDriverConnect
```

**Solution:**

If all conditions above are met, very likely your problem is that you are using Homebrew on an **Apple M1 Max** chip and you need to install it natively.
Once you have completed the Homebrew reinstallation you can check if `isql` manages to connect to the database.

To make the Python script work, you might need to reinstall Python using Homebrew. I would go for Python version 3.11.

When it comes to installing the pyodbc library use the `--no-binary` flag.

```
pip install --no-binary :all: pyodbc
```

[Unable to import pyodbc on Apple Silicon - Symbol not found: _SQLAllocHandle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66731036/unable-to-import-pyodbc-on-apple-silicon-symbol-not-found-sqlallochandle)